# `reset` and other methods of fully clearing terminal reset colour theme for fish

Tags: terminal, color-scheme, fish

I want to fully clear the terminal, not just scroll down. There are plenty of answers to this question already. However, I have found that the colour scheme gets changed (to the default one?) after doing this.
I am using termite as a terminal emulator.

Comment: As it is phrased now, this question is not about programming, so it's off-topic for Stack Overflow.  I'd recommend reposting it over on [Unix & Linux Stack](https://unix.stackexchange.com) or [Super User](https://superuser.com).  You'll probably also need to include some more details about how you are setting the color scheme, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reset` does a lot of things (among others it resets the terminal modes, which you don't care about here) and you just want to do one thing.

Use `clear`, which will also attempt to clear the terminal's scrollback if it can.

Comment: Using `clear` does not actually remove text for me, making it harder to see where the last output ended and the next one started, which is why I'm using `reset` in the first place.

Comment: That means you either don't have the ncurses version of clear (unlikely unless you're on  NetBSD), a very old ncurses version or your terminal doesn't advertise the "E3" capability - check $TERM. Again: `reset` is the wrong tool for this job. As a dirty hack: `printf "\033[H\033[2J\033[3J"` - this sends the sequence that xterm uses, which should also be what most other terminals use.

Comment: The 'dirty hack' (seems to have) worked perfectly. `$TERM` = `xterm-termite` and no, I'm not using NetBSD (:

Comment: Well, that terminfo [doesn't include e3](https://github.com/thestinger/termite/blob/master/termite.terminfo) (the "clear scrollback" capability). You could probably file a bug report, but the last commit to termite was in 2019, so it seems pretty dead.

Comment: Yeah, [termite is dead](https://github.com/thestinger/termite/issues/760).